# NPOI некорректная запись символа

Tags: c#, excel

Доброй ночи!
Записываю в файл xls с помощью NPOI строку

```
sheet_temp.GetRow(number).GetCell(8).SetCellValue(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds2);
```

hours,minutes, seconds2 - это строки

Открываю файл через office 2007. 
Данная ячейка используется у меня для вычисления значения в другой ячейке с помощью формулы СУММ.
Формула не считает, начинаю разбираться - формат строки в норме... строка похожа на существующую с которой СУММ работает. 
Пробую менять символы и оказывается что если поменять симво ':' на ввод символа ':' то всё сразу работает - как так?
Как мне записать в ячеку через NPOI чтобы не было конфликтов изза двоеточия?

Answer (score 1):

Есть подозрение, что дело не в символе ":", а в том, что после записи через `SetCellValue` формат ячейки строковый (поскольку Вы пишете в него строку). А после ручного ввода Excel определяет, что это дата - и выставляет нужный формат. А с правильным форматом уже работают формулы.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273949/npoi-date-format-cell) описана аналогичная проблема, попробуйте выставить формат ячейки:

```
IDataFormat dataFormatCustom = workbook.CreateDataFormat();
var cell=sheet_temp.GetRow(number).GetCell(8);
cell.CellStyle = styles["cell"]; 
cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = dataFormatCustom.GetFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```